# Need to write an equation exactly in the same way as in the picture

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, mathtools, cases

I have written my research paper in Ms word, but now I need it written in Latex, I am writing an equation of brier score which is as in the attached picture[image], that is, the bracket I want to be bigger enough to be rounded from two lines as I have written in ms word.

Comment: Try to use Mathpix.

Comment: Are you sure you want it exactly like that? The sum before the brace should probably be in display mode, the two squares sit on different heights, the "If texts" are smaller and why is that If with a capital I? Also, it is a bit uncommon to have a sum and then an opening brace like that.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}


\begin{document}
\[BS(t)=\frac1N \textstyle\sum_{i=1\ldots N}
  \begin{cases}
    (0-\hat{S}(t/z_i))^2  & \textup{if } t_i\leq t\\
    (1-\hat{S}(t/z_i))^2  & \textup{if } t_i > t
  \end{cases}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The font used is Cambria Math (use XeLaTeX engine). Here below there is a version with this font. You can observe that they are similar or equals. Adding to the previous MWE we have:

```
\usepackage{unicode-math} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}
```

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}

\begin{document}
\[BS(t)=\frac1N \textstyle\sum_{i=1\ldots N}
  \begin{cases}
    (0-\hat{S}(t/z_i))^2  & \textup{if } t_i\leq t\\
    (1-\hat{S}(t/z_i))^2  & \textup{if } t_i > t
  \end{cases}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working for me. Now i want to make it a bit larger than rest of the text and to bold it.  Further, while using it in another equation, I want to add some text after that 'if ti<t' there is no space after words. How to do them. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Basheer Ask a new question :-)

Answer (score 4):

[@Sebastiano's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/671881/5001) gives exactly what the OP *says* they want. Here's an alternative that may come closer to what the OP *should* want. :-) Obviously, the OP is free to choose a different symbol that `\mathcal{I}` to indicate the indicator function [pun intended].

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\begin{document}
Put $\mathcal{I}(t,t_i)=0$ if $t_i<t$ and $1$ if $t_i\ge t$. 
The Brier Score is given by
\[
\mathrm{BS}(t) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N
\bigl(\mathcal{I}(t,t_i)-\hat{S}(t/z_i)\bigr)^2 \,.
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you \infty for the citation. :-)